# chrome.alarms returns undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Good morning, wizards.

I'm trying myself in writing an extension for chromium-browser.
The version of chromium is `18.0.1025.151 (development build 130497 Linux) Built on Ubuntu 12.04, running on Ubuntu 12.10`

My OS is ubuntu GNU/Linux 12.04.1 (LTS), 64bit.

The problem is: I cannot use `chrome.alarms`. I get 'undefined' when access this variable.

Part of my `manifest.json`:

```
  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
  "permissions": [
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*"
  ],
```

Part of my `background.js`:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(function(alarm) {
    if (! alarm.name.match ('/^extension47_.*/'))
        return;
    alert ('extension47 fired an alarm!');
});
```

What I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onAlarm' of undefined
```

at the line `chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener`.

When I go to the chromium console from the extensions page, auto-completion suggests me no `chrome.alarms`. Obviously, when I type there `chrome.alarms`, I really get `undefined`. Why so?..

I'm totally stuck, failed to find a solution anywhere on the Internet, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least Google Chrome 22.

```
Availability:   Google Chrome 22
```

http://developer.chrome.com/trunk/extensions/alarms.html

Comment: wow. I read the 'stable' version of this doc page, and there is no word about availability o_O. Weird.

Answer (score 16):

I had some trouble with this too recently and didn't see that noted anywhere in the docs (or at any relevant location).

Just make sure to also ask for the `alarms` permission:

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "permissions": [
        // ...  
        "alarms"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Bless you kind stranger, this was driving me crazy

Answer (score 1):

You will need to install Chromium from a 3rd party maintained repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:a-v-shkop/chromium
sudo add-apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

This will give you Version 23.0.1271.64 Ubuntu 12.04 (165188).

Answer (score 1):

Just adding one scenario to the answers : **don't forget to refresh your extension.**

If - like me - you didn't delete your (unpacked) extension before adding the alarms permission in the manifest, but just deactivated it (dev/debug), **the alarm permission won't register** (actually, no source modification would register at all). Just a silly case.

Either you must activate your extension **and refresh it**, or delete it then load it again. Only then the extension is granted alarms permission and the test doesn't return `undefined` any longer.