# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAlarm')

Tags: reactjs, webpack, google-chrome-extension, service-worker, content-script

I'm trying to use an alarm in my chrome extension, but when I add a listener to listen to when the alarm has expired, I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onAlarm')

This is how I'm calling the listener:

```
chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener(
    function(alarm){
        console.log(alarm)
    },
  )
```

I've also added `alarms` to the permissions in `manifest.json`. I'm clueless regarding what exactly is causing this issue, any help is appreciated.

Kindly refer to the below code snippets for further context, the files are written in TypeScript and then compiled to JS using `webpack`.

**content.ts**

```
function inject(msg: ChromeMessage, sender: chrome.runtime.MessageSender, sendResponse: (response: DOMMessageResponse) => void) {

    

    console.log("Listener called")
    const portal = document.createElement("div");

    portal.style.position = "absolute";
    portal.style.zIndex = "9999";
    portal.style.top = "0";
    portal.style.left = "0";
    portal.style.width = "100%";
    portal.style.height = "100vh";
    portal.id = "portal";
    

    const root = portal.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    
    document.body.appendChild(portal);
    
    
    const innerDiv = document.createElement("div");
    innerDiv.id = "innerDiv";
    root.appendChild(innerDiv)
    
    
    innerDiv.style.width = "100%";
    innerDiv.style.height = "100%";
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(DOMContent), innerDiv);
    return true
    
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(inject);
```

**background.ts**

```
export {}

const periodInMinutes  = 5;

chrome.alarms.create( "myAlarm", { periodInMinutes } );


chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener( ( alarm ) => {
    console.log( 'alarm!', alarm );
});
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Extension",
  "description": "Extension 1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action":{
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Alarm"
  },
  "permissions":[
    "alarms",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting"
    
  ],
  "host_permissions":[
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["./content.js"]
        
    }
  ],
  "background":{
    "service_worker":"./background.js"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo192.png",
    "48": "logo192.png",
    "128": "logo192.png"
 
  }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72536047/5089567

Comment: Hello @KonradLinkowski, I have included `alarms` in the `permissions` section and also tried uninstalling and loading the unpacked extension, but the issue still persists, what else could be wrong?

Comment: I got the same issue and am clueless of how to resolve this. the alarms object just isn't available in the chrome/browser object

Answer (score 1):

Let's cover the bases here. Making no assumptions on what you have or have not coded, you'll need to do the following, minimum:

**manifest.json**

```
"manifest_version" : 3

,"background" : { 
    "service_worker" : "background.js"
}

,"permissions" : [
    "alarms"
]
```

**background.js**

```
const periodInMinutes  = 5;

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener( details => {
    chrome.alarms.create( "myAlarm", { periodInMinutes } );
});

chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener( ( alarm ) => {
    console.log( 'alarm!', alarm );
});
```

The output of which should be something similar to

```
alarm! {name: 'myAlarm', periodInMinutes: 5, scheduledTime: 1660923406980.613}
```

Comment: Hello @Mac, I'd already included `alarms` in the `permissions`, however, I changed my background script to be similar to the snippet you have shown above, now it instead says, `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')`, any Idea what exactly is causing this issue?

Comment: @Prajwal Kulkarni: Without seeing the exact code you're using, I can't know. In my own testing, I get the error you report when my `permissions` does not include `alarms`.

Comment: I've updated the question with added code for further reference, kindly check.

Comment: This is intermediate source code you're displaying here (TypeScript prior to Webpack). What does your actual (deployable) `./background.js` file look like?

Comment: `(()=>{"use strict";chrome.alarms.create("myAlarm",{periodInMinutes:5}),chrome.alarms.onAlarm.addListener((function(r){console.log("alarm!",r)}))})();`. The code is minified to be inline as the mode is set to `production`.

Comment: I dropped this in to my test setup without errors. The alarm fired. Something in your environment is janking with `chrome.alarms`, but I couldn't tell you what. Sorry.

Comment: Hey @Mac, there indeed was some issue with my environment that was causing the problem. My extension makes use of content script as well, but using content script is throwing the `onAlarm` error, To verify, I tried removing the content script, and the alarm just fired fine. Any workarounds you could suggest for this?

Comment: @Prajwal Kulkarni, okay good, you're on the right track. The error appears to 1) be either in the content script itself, or 2) is manifested by the way your content script interacts with your extension. If you post your compiled content script, I might be able to help. Otherwise, you will have to go through the logic piece by piece.

Comment: Well, the compiled code is minified and hard to read, instead, you'd want to go through the source code of the content script [here](https://github.com/prajwalkulkarni/take-a-break/blob/main/src/chromeServices/content.ts). Another thing I could notice is that the alarm is fired within the context of the popup extension, does that mean the alarm fires only as long as the popup is open?

Comment: I looked at your pre-compiled content script and afraid I'm not of much help. As for testing your popup, just keep it open and monitor your background script web worker. Then close the popup and see if alarms still fire.